# es6 array return all items up to a certain conditional or the first item if all items meet condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

given the following data:

```
const array = [
  {name: one, completed: false},
  {name: two, completed: false},
  {name: three, completed: false},
  {name: four, completed: false},
]

const arrayTwo = [
  {name: one, completed: true},
  {name: two, completed: true},
  {name: three, completed: false},
  {name: four, completed: false},
]
```

I need to be able to return:

```
//from array
[
  {name: one, completed: false}
]

//from arrayTwo
[
  {name: one, completed: true},
  {name: two, completed: true},
  {name: three, completed: false},
]
```

**So to the question:**
How can I map/filter/reduce these arrays to return all items **up to and including** the first one with the param meeting condition of:

```
completed: false
```

...or the first one if they all meet the condition of:

```
completed: false
```

**As always any and all direction is greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!**

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing your solution attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  const result = array.slice(0, array.findIndex(it => !it.completed) + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a simple solution to my query, apologies if it was not asked in the right manner or under the big brother guidelines down voted here within.  I thought we were all here to help each other, but alas some have more time on their hands than others...

Comment: @studiobrain on another day, the question migh've been upvoted. I only downvote spam and unreadable questions but some other people do follow different rules. At the end its just reputation, a number stored somewhere on a computer, who cares really?

Comment: There is however the "show what you've tried" rule, which you could follow the next time ...

Comment: So hypocrisy is your justification?  You have posted on this thread 3 times, so I see that you do indeed care, and for that I thank you!  ...sure, next time I will post all of my failed attempts in an effort to cull the amount of spam the post might contain vs brevity.  I received the answer I needed so vote however.

Comment: @srudiobrain Just don't take votes personally. Some of my answers also get downvoted (especially the good ones) while bad answers (like this one) get upvotes. The voting system only works for questions that get visited more often, for questions that get less attention it depends on the mood of the 20 people visiting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop, keep pushing values to `op` and once you found `completed` return `op`

```js
const array = [{name: 'one', completed: false},{name: 'two', completed: false},{name: 'three', completed: false},{name: 'four', completed: false},]

const arrayTwo = [{name: 'one', completed: true},{name: 'two', completed: true},{name: 'three', completed: false},{name: 'four', completed: false},]

const fn = arr => {
  let op = []
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    op.push(arr[i])
    if(!arr[i].completed){
      return op
    }
  }
}

console.log(fn(array))

console.log(fn(arrayTwo))
```